# Spring Android authentication with Spring Security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following configuration in my `security-context`

```
        <!-- web services-->
        <http use-expressions="true" pattern="/services/**"
            disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
            <intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"
                requires-channel="https" />
            <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="restSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="restAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
            <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
        </http>
        <!-- browser -->
        <http use-expressions="true"
            disable-url-rewriting="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/signup*" access="permitAll"
                requires-channel="https" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"
                requires-channel="https" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"
                requires-channel="https" />
            <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/loginFailed" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()"
                requires-channel="https" />
            <session-management
                session-authentication-error-url="/loginFailed">
                <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
                    max-sessions="1" />
            </session-management>
            <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
        </http>
```

and my springSecurityFilterChain is as

```
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

I am not able to perform login with

```
template.postForObject(targetURL + "services/j_spring_security_check", map,
                String.class);
```

each time I tried it give me error as

```
POST request for "https://localhost:8443/someapp/services/j_spring_security_check" resulted in 401 (Unauthorized);
```

If I modify the url by removing `services` the error goes away. But I would like to differentiate between rest login (from mobile) and normal login (from browser). For rest login I'd like to return sessionID instead of redirecting to welcome page. What did I do wrong here ?

**UPDATED**

This is how I create the HTTP client:

```
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "d:/somekeystore");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "1234");
        String targetURL = "https://localhost:8443/someapp/";
        // configure HTTPClient and RestTemplate
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory commons = new CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                client);
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(commons);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        map.add("j_username", "admin");
        map.add("j_password", "1234");
        map.add("rest", "true");
        template.postForObject(targetURL + "services/j_spring_security_check", map,
                String.class);
```

Comment: Check out this SO thread, it might help: stackoverflow.com/questions/4783063/… Your approach may have to change slightly, but it should be possible to do what you're trying

Comment: I am checking it out now, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the `401 (Unauthorized)` error with specifying `login-processing-url` within `<form-login>` as

```
<form-login login-processing-url="/services/j_spring_security_check"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="restSuccessHandler"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="restAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess it's cause you have the /services/** to require full authentication, but that's also the location to which you're trying to submit the login.

Try adding a login-page="services/login" and a "services/login" intercept-url with permitAll and use that as the login... ie:

```
<!-- web services-->
<http use-expressions="true" pattern="/services/**" disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/services/login*" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/services/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https" />
    <form-login login-page="/services/login" authentication-success-handler-ref="restSuccessHandler" authentication-failure-handler-ref="restAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
</http>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think my guess about the cause is probably the root of why you get the 401, but I don't think the solution is as simple as I'd hoped. I commented on the OP with a link to another SO thread where someone seems to be trying to do a variation of what you are trying to do.